# Selenium Video Node api

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I am using  [selenium video node api](https://github.com/aimmac23/selenium-video-node) for recording remote machine screen but when I run server or hub it run perfectly but it give error when I start node or client.

**Hub Run**

```
java -cp selenium-video-node-1.4.jar;selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher -servlets com.aimmac23.hub.servlet.HubVideoDownloadServlet -role hub
```

**Node Run**

```
java -cp selenium-video-node-1.4.jar;selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher -servlets com.aimmac23.node.servlet.VideoRecordingControlServlet -proxy com.aimmac23.hub.proxy.VideoProxy -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.2.245:4444/grid/register -port 6666
```

**It give error like**

```
11:51:30.817 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:6666/wd/hub

11:51:31.254 INFO - Could not load 64 bit native libraries - attempting 32 bit i
nstead Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'vpx': The specified module could not be found.

    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:169)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:242)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:368)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:353)
    at com.aimmac23.node.jna.JnaLibraryLoader.tryLoadLibraries(JnaLibraryLoader.java:125)
    at com.aimmac23.node.jna.JnaLibraryLoader.tryBitDepth(JnaLibraryLoader.java:150)
    at com.aimmac23.node.jna.JnaLibraryLoader.init(JnaLibraryLoader.java:110)
    at com.aimmac23.node.RecordVideoCallable.<clinit>(RecordVideoCallable.java:26)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.aimmac23.node.servlet.VideoRecordingControlServlet.<clinit>(VideoRecordingControlServlet.java:40)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.utils.ExtraServletUtil.createServlet(ExtraServletUtil.java:38)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.SelfRegisteringRemote.startRemoteServer(SelfRegisteringRemote.java:123)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:115)
```

Please Help me.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest video node which at 2015-02-06 is https://aimmac23.com/public/maven-repository/com/aimmac23/selenium-video-node/1.6/

I'm running on a 64 bit machines - it may be that if the 64 bit native libraries don't load then the 32 bit libraries are loaded and the exception you're seeing the exception from the first attempt.  You can check for yourself, the code is at: https://github.com/aimmac23/selenium-video-node

-Anton